# Compute limit $f(x,y)=(x+y)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Compute limit $$f(x,y)=(x+y)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$ as $(x,y)\to\infty$ meaning that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to \infty$

What I did was note that $x+y < x^2+y^2$ as $x\to\infty$ $y\to\infty$ and then taking $(x^2+y^2)=u$ we get limit as $0$. But this is wrong when I realized that $(x,y) \to\infty$ does not mean  that $x\to\infty$ ,$y\to\infty$ but $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to\infty$ . How proceed?

So if I can show that $x+y \to\infty$ then we can use above method

Comment: $$|x+y|\le|x|+|y|\le\sqrt{(|x|+|y|)^2+(|x|-|y|)^2}=\sqrt{2\!\left(x^2+y^2\right)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$|f(x,y)|\le (|x|+|y|)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\le \sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}.$$ Substitute $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and compute the limit
$$\lim_{r\to +\infty} re^{-r^2}.$$